# Confusion with "this" in javascript code

Tags: javascript, this, cascade

I got this js code and run it,it works perfectly fine except that, I don't understand it entirely.
Please help!!

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="members-wrapper"></div>


 <script>

  var db = [
     {fname:"oscar", lname:"santosh", email:"oscar@gmail.com", country:"Brazil", id:101},
      {fname:"juan", lname:"mata", email:"mata@gmail.com", country:"Spain", id:102},
   {fname:"eden", lname:"hazard", email:"hazard@gmail.com", country:"Belgium", id:103}
  ];

  function CaseName(str)
    {
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
    };

  //our object with channable method

  var cascadeVar ={

    user:"",

    finduser: function(userEmail)
    {
       var arraylen = db.length,i;
       for(i=arraylen-1;i>=0;i--)
       {
         if(db[i].email === userEmail )
         {
          this.user = db[i];
           break;
         }
       }
       return this;
    },

    formatname : function()
    {
    if(this.user){
       this.user.fullname = CaseName(this.user.fname) + " " + CaseName(this.user.lname);
       }
       return this;
    },

    createLayout:function () {
    if (this.user) {
    this.user.viewData = "<h2>Member: " + this.user.fullname + "</h2>" + "<p>ID: " + this.user.id + "</p>" + "<p>Email: " + this.user.email + "</p>";
    }
    return this;
    },

    display : function()
    {

    if (!this.user) return;
    $(".members-wrapper").append(this.user.viewData);
    }   

  };

  cascadeVar.finduser("oscar@gmail.com").formatname().createLayout().display();

 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

In the function finduser, why do i have to use this as `this.user = db[i];` ?
Is it because user belongs to the object cascadeVar and this points to cascadeVar.
If yes, Why won't it work without "this" ?I know i am being silly but I still am confused.

Will user be undefined inside the function finduser(), if I ignore `this`.?

What is `return this` returning in the same function?

What is `return this` returning is every single function?

Please help!

Comment: The `return this;` part in every method allows you to chain methods.

Comment: HOW?? please explain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In javascript each function has a context. That's the thing we call `this`.
The thing is that by default, the function's context is the functions; parent object. So, yes, your assumption is right: *user belongs to the object cascadeVar and this points to cascadeVar*.

I often find that code can speak for itself, so let's take an example to understand how `this` works:

```js
function getName() {
  // what is `this` ?
  return this.userName;
}

var user1 = {
  userName: 'john',
  getName: getName
};

var user2 = {
  userName: 'george'
}

// getName is a global function, meaning that it's parent is window
// in this case, `this` will point to the window object
// and `this.userName` will point to window.userName
// which is undefined
console.log('getName() =>', getName());

// user1.getName is a user1 method, meaning that it's parent is user1
// in this case, `this` will point to user1
// and `this.userName` will point to user1.userName
// which is 'john'
console.log('user1.getName() =>', user1.getName());

// there are other ways that we can dynamically change a function's context
// look into the following function methods: `call`, `apply`, `bind`
console.log('getName.call(user2) =>', getName.call(user2));
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

Regarding your other question, all the methods return the `this` keyword in order to ensure  the method chaining. This is a design pattern made popular by the jQuery library and it lets you sequentially call multiple methods of the same object without recalling the parent object.
This basically lets you do some syntactic sugar like calling `a.b().c().d();` instead of  `a.b(); a.c(); a.d();`.
And.. of course, here's a snippet of code that shows chaining in use:

```js
var calculator = {
  value: 0,
  add: function(n) {
    this.value += n;
    return this;
  },
  substract: function(n) {
    this.value -= n;
    return this;
  },
  multiply: function(n) {
    this.value *= n;
    return this;
  }
};

calculator
  .add(6)
  .substract(2)
  .multiply(2)
  .add(3)
  .substract(5);

console.log('(6 - 2) * 2 + 3 - 5 = ', calculator.value);
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

Comment: How all method returning `this` ensure channing ?

Comment: in my example, when the `add` function returns `this`, it actually returns it's parent: `calculator`. So basically, after being evaluated, the function has the `calculator` value: `calculator.add(1) === calculator`.

Answer (score 0):

*This* in Javascript refers to the owner object of the current function ( in this case cascadeVar)

Without it the JS interpreter would understand user to be a dynamic variable scoped to the findUser function

In each case *this* is returning the owner of the current function i.e. cascadeVar.

The original author gave you a clue in saying the method is 'channable' (i.e. chainable). By returning the cascadeVar object internally, the function allows recursive function calls.